# large cookies casusing 413 error apache2 php

Tags: php, apache, cookies, varnish

having a pretty frustrating issue with large cookies causing  the 413 Request too large error, have read through tones of articles and tried the following with no luck

so we've set these in apache2

```
LimitRequestBody 5000000
LimitRequestFieldSize 5000000
LimitRequestLine 5000000
LimitXMLRequestBody 5000000
```

this in varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80,:443 \
         -p http_req_size=65536 \
         -p http_resp_size=65536 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,1500M
```

and this in php.ini

```
post_max_size = 64M  upload_max_filesize = 64M
```

this in modsecurity.conf

`SecRequestBodyLimit 32768000 SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 32768000 SecRequestBodyAccess On`

this has made no difference at all?  if anyone has any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: don't store data in cookies.... store data in your database. use an encrypted value in your cookie to decode to a database key to load the data. or store it in a serialized file, and use the decrypted cookie value to load the file.(sessions usually work like this)

Comment: we do generally with our own data, this is a third party setting the cookie thus pushing the size up..

Comment: You're not clear on where the error comes from. Did you see backend request in Apache log or the error is returned directly by Varnish?

Comment: seems to be pointing to a varnish issue, as page loads fine when bypassing.  but not getting much at all from either log - nothing flags in apache and varnishncsa just gives me the user agents :/

Comment: was the `http_req_hdr_len` flag in varnish conf if anyone runs into the problem